# Updating cumulative sum ordered by two columns

Tags: sql, sqlite, cumulative-sum

Given the table:

```
id   date count cumulative_sum
1    2    100                  
2    1    50
3    1    10
4    2    5
```

How do I update `cumulative_sum` of the rows ordered by `date`, `id`?

The result should be:

```
id   date count cumulative_sum
2    1    50    50
3    1    10    60
1    2    100   160
4    2    5     165
```

Is it also possible to update only those rows that need to be recalculated when I insert or update a row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this:

```
update your_table
set
  cumulative_sum = (select sum(c)
                    from your_table t2
                    where
                      t2.date<your_table.date
                      or (t2.date=your_table.date
                          and t2.id<=your_table.id));
```

Subquery counts the cumulative sum of the count, which is the sum of all values where the date is < than the date of the current row, or where the date = the date of the current row and the id is <.

You could also put this condition:

```
where cumulative_sum is null
```

That updates the rows only if there's not a value already. This will work if all ids and dates inserted in the table are always in ascending order.

Answer (score 0):

First sort the table in the desired order and then use below query put it into `#temp`

```
Declare @count int=0

UPdate #temp Set @count = cumulative_sum =  count + @count
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `ORDER BY` function for `date` column.

`SELECT * FROM yourTableName ORDER BY date`